# How to keep apps separate per user in iTunes?

Tags: iphone, itunes, ios-appstore

My husband and I are currently sharing a computer and due to the limited data on the iCloud we both like to create a backup of our cell phones on the computer. With each iOS update I like to reset my phone as new and then restore it from a backup. The problem with this is that every time I restore it, it's putting both mine and my husbands apps on my phone. We tried creating different profiles on the mac and backing up our phones under our own profile, but for whatever reason all the apps still combines. Now half the time I have to enter his password on my phone or vice versa if there's an app that needs updating.

What if anything can I possible do (without having to buy another Mac of course) to keep our apps separate?

Comment: Are you using joint computer and/or iCloud accounts?

Answer (score 1):

If you have separate profiles set up already, your husband's apps shouldn't be transferring over upon restore EXCEPT if the iPhone backup already contains your husband's apps. Make sure to:

1. Remove all of your husband's apps from the iPhone
2. Back up the iPhone using your iTunes profile

The next time you restore, the apps should only come from your Apple account.